# How to add a button using data detail to a string made in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to create different sections with strings of information and they are displaying on my screen. I now want to add a button to each section which uses data detail to store the name and the price in the button. I tried by just adding a button into the string using data detail but due to having to use different "" and '' it made the string incomplete and could not complete the code.

```
function display(results) {
    article = document.getElementById("homeArticle");
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){ 
        var item = results[i];

        var name = item.P_NAME;
        var description = item.P_DESCRIPTION;
        var price = item.P_PRICE;
        var quant = item.P_QUANTITY;
            // next I add to the string that we want to place on the page
        html += '<section id="homePageSection"> <p>Name: ' + name + '</p><p>Description: ' + description + '</p><p>Price: £' + price + '</p><p>Quantity: ' + quant + '</p></section>';

        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.dataset.detail = JSON.stringify(name);
        button.innerHTML = "Add To Basket"

        var section = document.getElementById("homePageSection");

    };
    article.innerHTML = html;
}


function getItems() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var results = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        display(results.rows);
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "displayData.php");
    xhr.send();
}

window.addEventListener("load", getItems);
```

I have tried to use the following code after looking at other answers to questions with similar problems:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.dataset.detail = JSON.stringify(name);
button.innerHTML = "Add To Basket"

var section = document.getElementById("homePageSection");
```

However I am not quite understanding how this works and need help being pointed in the right direction, is there anyway you can do it with just data detail or do you need to use the `document.createElement` and `appendChild` code?

html page is:

```
<body>

<article id="homeArticle">
</article>

<script src="homeDisplay.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats fiddle with example: https://jsfiddle.net/03jqfx6g/

thats ans:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.dataset.detail = JSON.stringify(name);
button.innerHTML = "Add To Basket"

document.getElementById("homePageSection").appendChild(btn);
```

Comment: i get an error message in the console saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`

Comment: it is because u have not element with id homePageSection - show your html, or better - create fiddle with example, and i solve it trouble right in fiddle @thomas

Comment: okay as this is homework i will try and solve it in fiddle, if i have problems later i will  try and comment again. Thank you for your help @legendary

Comment: i mean - create in fiddle example of ur html, and i write js-code : D @thomas

Comment: okay will do, my html is very simple, its just an emtpy article, here it is, https://jsfiddle.net/03jqfx6g/

Comment: i see i was using the wrong id element but i want the button to be added to each section that i have created with the detail of the name and price and this is where i get confused.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is in jquery, suppose you have a div named "container"

then try the folowing code

```
// under the event , like button click
    var your_dynamic_value = 'xyz';
    $("#container").append('<input type="submit" value="'+your_dynamic_value+'">');
```

Hope it helps....